# replace NULL with Blank value or Zero in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-null

I have a temp table and in that one of my column `total_amount` is of integer type and NOT `NULL`. While querying data, I received `NULL` values for `total_Amount` column.

How ever I used following syntax to remove nulls but some how still NULL values appearing, correct me if I am wrong.

```
Create table #Temp1
(
    issue varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    total_amount int NOT NULL
)
```

This is my query

```
Case when total_amount = 0 then 0  
else isnull(total_amount, 0)  
end as total_amount
```

I am facing issue at my else part.

Comment: Can you post the entire query? Although it seems to be ok, both your table declaration and what you select.

Comment: should be Left Join issue, please post your query

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the COALESCE function to automatically return null values as 0. Syntax is as shown below:

```
SELECT COALESCE(total_amount, 0) from #Temp1
```

Comment: I prefer the ISNULL() also see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce/

Answer (score 4):

The coalesce() is the best solution when there are multiple columns [and]/[or] values and you want the first one.  However, looking at books on-line, the query optimize converts it to a case statement.

***MSDN excerpt***

The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE expression.

That is, the code COALESCE(expression1,...n) is rewritten by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression:

```
CASE
   WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1
   WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2
   ...
   ELSE expressionN
END
```

**With that said, why not a simple ISNULL()?  Less code = better solution?**

Here is a complete code snippet.

```
-- drop the test table
drop table #temp1
go

-- create test table
create table #temp1
(
    issue varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    total_amount int NULL
); 
go

-- create test data
insert into #temp1 values
    ('No nulls here', 12),
    ('I am a null', NULL);
go

-- isnull works fine
select
    isnull(total_amount, 0) as total_amount  
from #temp1
```

**Last but not least, how are you getting null values into a NOT NULL column?**

I had to change the table definition so that I could setup the test case.  When I try to alter the table to NOT NULL, it fails since it does a nullability check.

```
-- this alter fails
alter table #temp1 alter column total_amount int NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

**Different ways to replace NULL in sql server**

Replacing NULL value using:

**1.**  ISNULL() function

**2.** COALESCE() function

**3.** CASE Statement

```
SELECT Name as EmployeeName, ISNULL(Bonus,0) as EmployeeBonus from tblEmployee

SELECT Name as EmployeeName, COALESCE(Bonus, 0) as EmployeeBonus 
FROM tblEmployee

SELECT Name as EmployeeName, CASE WHEN Bonus IS NULL THEN 0 
ELSE Bonus  END as EmployeeBonus 
FROM  tblEmployee
```

Comment: `iif (column is null, 'null', 'not null')` what about this.?

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
SELECT Title  from #Movies
    SELECT CASE WHEN Title = '' THEN 'No Title' ELSE Title END AS Titile from #Movies
```

OR

```
SELECT [Id], [CategoryId], ISNULL(nullif(Title,''),'No data') as Title, [Director], [DateReleased] FROM #Movies
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace Null Values as Empty: `ISNULL('Value','')`

Replace Null Values as 0: `ISNULL('Value',0)`

Answer (score 1):

You should always return the same type on all case condition:

In the first one you have an character and on the else you have an int.

You can use:

```
Select convert(varchar(11),isnull(totalamount,0))
```

or if you want with your solution:

```
Case when total_amount = 0 then '0'   
else convert(varchar(11),isnull(total_amount, 0))  
end as total_amount
```

Comment: i have changed my comment, it has to return INT type.

Comment: I provided the solution when the text was with a string on case statement, if he wants a int:
    select isnull(totalamount,0)